# How to validate two radio buttons, user should be to select any of the two radio button(Email or Phone)

Tags: javascript, html

How to validate two radio buttons, the user should be able to select any of the two radio button(Email or Phone) then text box field will appear. if the user selects any one Radio button I want to validate field(Phone or Email) using Javascript.

This is what I tried!

```js
function validation() 
{
var em = document.getElementById("eid").value.indexOf("@");
var ph = document.getElementById("ph").value;
if(em==-1) 
{  
alert("E-mail ID is not valid");
return false;
}
else if(ph==""||ph==null)
{
alert("Enter The Phone No");
return false;
}
else if(isNaN(ph)||ph.length>10||ph.length<10)
{
alert("The mobile no. always has 10 digit numerical value");
return false;
}
else{
alert("Your Information is Submitted Successfully");
}

</script>

         </tr>
         </html>
```

```html
<html>
 <style>
#Phone:checked ~ .Phone
{
display:block;
}
#Email:checked ~ .Email
{
display:block;
}
</style>
 
 <tr>
            <td align="right">
               <label>Email</label>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
               <input type="radio" name="data" id="Email">
               <div class="Email" hidden>
                 <input type="text" id="eid" placeholder="Enter your Email" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <label>Phone</label>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
               <input type="radio" name="data" id="Phone">
               <div class="Phone" hidden>
               <input type="text" id="ph" minlength="1" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter your phone number" />
               </div>
            </td>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' onclick="validation();" />
         </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When one of radio buttons clicked then text `input` tag's hidden value get false/true on its condition.

```js
let radio = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='data']");

function addEventListener(radio1, radio2) 
{
  radio1.onclick = function(e) 
  {
  let textInput = document.getElementsByClassName(e.target.id)[0];  
  let state = textInput.hidden ? false : true;
  textInput.hidden = state; 
  
  let otherInput = document.getElementsByClassName(radio2.id)[0];
  otherInput.hidden = true;
  }
  
}

addEventListener(radio[0], radio[1]);
addEventListener(radio[1], radio[0]);

function validation() 
{
var emHidden = document.getElementsByClassName("Email")[0].hidden;
var phHidden = document.getElementsByClassName("Phone")[0].hidden
var em = document.getElementById("eid").value.indexOf("@");
var ph = document.getElementById("ph").value;
if(em==-1 && !emHidden) 
{  
alert("E-mail ID is not valid");
return false;
} 
else if(!phHidden) 
{
  if(ph==""||ph==null)
  {
  alert("Enter The Phone No");
  return false;
  }
  else if(isNaN(ph)||ph.length>10||ph.length<10)
  {
  alert("The mobile no. always has 10 digit numerical value");
  return false;
  }

} 
alert("Your Information is Submitted Successfully");
}
```

```html
<html>
 <tr>
            <td align="right">
               <label>Email</label>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
               <input type="radio" name="data" id="Email">
               <div class="Email" hidden>
                 <input type="text" id="eid" placeholder="Enter your Email" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <label>Phone</label>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
               <input type="radio" name="data" id="Phone">
               <div class="Phone" hidden>
               <input type="text" id="ph" minlength="1" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter your phone number" />
               </div>
            </td>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' onclick="validation();" />
         </html>
```

Comment: When i click one Phone radio button phone validation is not happening rather it is asking email and also it should be optional for user to enter either Phone or email and then validate accordingly selected radio button

Comment: @Asher So when selecting the Phone radio button and clicking the submit button then the validation function should fire, right? And other conditions in the validation function should be activated on each condition?

Comment: @Asher Edited and check plz

Comment: please check your mail.

Comment: when I click on phone its working fine but when I click on an email it is not working.

Comment: @Asher Could you explain how the email is not working exactly?

Comment: @Asher Was my answer helpful? If it was then please select my answer.

Comment: I have shared how it is not working please check your mail.

Comment: @Asher fixed email. Check the answer, please.

Comment: other validations stopped working please check your email for details.